# Avoiding instance construction of return type while generating stub for method

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have issue while trying to mock method that returns instance of abstract class with Rhino Mocks. Issue is that MammalBase constructor is invoked while stub is created and I would like to avoid that. All source code in question is locked for editing and only tests can be changed.

Eventually, base class is processing something by type attributes in constructor, and throws exception if no adequate attributes are detected. That causes a extensive logging.
My hope is to remove unnecessary logs from tests.

Is it possible to instruct Rhino Mocks not to instantiate return type (MammalBase) when it creates proxy while creating a stub?

Is explicit attribute or type setting possible for return value while Rhino creates stub for method with abstract class instance as return type?

Is avoiding constructor even possible without making stubbed method return interface?

I found that issue does not exist if:
1. Stubbed method returns array like MammalBase[],
2. Stubbed method returns derivate class like "Human" first, since no more constructors of base class are invoked.

Thanks in advance!

(Code sample)

```
public interface IDetermineMammalByType
    {
        MammalBase DetermineMammalByType(MammalBase creature);
    }

public abstract class MammalBase
{
    protected MammalBase()
    {
        CustomAttribute[] attributes = (CustomAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(this.GetType(), typeof(CustomAttribute));

        if (!attributes.Any(x=> x as CustomAttribute != null))
        {
            //This causes issue
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

[CustomAttribute()]
public class Human : MammalBase { }

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class |
                       System.AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class CustomAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public CustomAttribute() { }
}

public class MammalDetector : IDetermineMammalByType
{
    public MammalBase DetermineMammalByType(MammalBase creature)
    {
        //Some logic
        return null;
    }
}

//TEST
[TestMethod()]
public void DetermineMammalByTypeTest()
{
    IDetermineMammalByType myTest = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDetermineMammalByType>();
    var creature = new Human();

    //Here it fails while mocking method
    myTest.Stub(x => x.DetermineMammalByType(creature)).Return(new Human());
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it should throw an exception. The question is very hard to understand and very much text to read. Are you sure that you can reproduce it with this code? Aren't you trying to mock the `MammalBase` somewhere, causing the exception because the mock doesn't have an attribute?

Comment: What is the `MammalDetector`used for? It is not used anywhere, but it is not possible to instantiate it, because it derives from `MammalBase` but doesn't have an attribute on it.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Stefan, MammalBase inheritance was added to MammalDetector by mistake while I was creating sample project. Issue comes since method DetermineMammalByType is returning actual instance (not interface). It appears that Rhino will create a new instance of (something that inherits) MamalBase when it reads method signature while creating stub. My guess is for keeping internal return value. I would like to avoid this since base class constructor validates itself and throws exception which causes extensive logging. Thanks!